# Find greatest X shape in a binary matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I recently had a technical test for a company, and they had, I think, a really interesting problem about recognizing a shape in a binary matrix.

The goal of the exercise was to create an algorithm that could find the biggest X shape in a binary matrix, and return its length. An X is defined in this way :
-A X is composed of two diagonals of equal length, that share a unique point. 
For example :

```
101
010
101
```

Contains a valid X of length 3,so the algorithm will return 3.

```
1001
0110
0110
1001
```

Doesn't contain any valid X, so the algorithm will return 1,since a 1-length X is a single 1.

I managed to do the exercise, but I implemented a very messy algorithm, with time complexity estimated at O(n3), which is bad and unsuitable for very large matrix. A large part of this complexity is the double for loop I used to go through the matrix.

What could I have done to make a cleaner algorithm? I ask the question out of personal interest, and need to improve my skills and practical thinking.

Comment: Does the X need to be 'outlined' in zeroes? Or (for example) will an array of all ones be considered to have an X that spans the whole grid?

Comment: @ruakh it doesn't need to be outlined by 0. As long as it satisfies the condition of 2 equals diagonals sharing one unique point.

Comment: By the way, I think the *cleanest* algorithm is O(n^3). Don't confuse "messy" with "slow"!

Comment: I actually went through several iterations, and my current iteration is a bit faster, I believe! Long story short, I check every element in the array, and when I find a 1, I try to check how much I can extend its diagonals to check for the biggest X possible.

Comment: If there is no 'outline' requirement, what does the "equal diagonals" then mean? (since one may now be longer than the other).

Comment: The equal diagonal requirement means that the two diagonals are of the same length and share a unique 1. I edited the first post for clarity !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're OK with O(n^2) extra space, then one option is to build two extra arrays: one to record the length of the longest `\` shape centered at each cell, one to record the length of the longest `/`. (You can build each one in O(n^2) time by using a triply-nested loop -- which might sound like O(n^3) time, but the memoization means that you only need to iterate *once* over any given `\` or `/`, so the innermost loop can be amortized-constant time.) You then iterate over all positions; for any position, the largest `X` centered at that position has size equal to the lesser of the two matrices' values at that position. Just track the greatest such lesser value, and you're done.

That has worst-case time complexity of O(n^2), which is clearly asymptotically optimal.

Comment: Actually, one extra array is enough, you can combine the scan of the other direction with the last step.

Comment: @Henry: That's a good point. That's still O(n^2) extra space; but if the input is an array of integers, and if we're OK with (temporarily) mutating its contents, then we can actually use the input-array itself as one of the "extra" arrays. That, plus your suggestion, would eliminate any need for extra space (other than O(1) space for local variables and whatnot).

Answer (score 1):

Althogh not clearly specified in the question, I assume the common point of the two diagonals must be in the middle to form a valid "X" shape. The pictures seem to support this assumption.

Imagine the array is rotated by 45 degrees so that we have now some kind of diamond shape. We are now searching for crosses aligned to the x and y axes.

You can check line by line for spans of ones. Only a span with an odd number of ones can possibly be part of a cross (otherwise there is no middle element).

For each such span, check if there is really a cross.

If we are just interested in the maximum size you can leave out the cross check if the span is shorter or equal than the maximum found so far.

The time needed to identify the horizontal spans is O(n^2).
For each horizontal span of lenght m you check at most m+2 elements in the other direction. The sum of the lengths of all spans is clearly O(n^2) so the time necessary for the cross checks is also O(n^2).

The total effort for this algorithm is therefore O(n^2) and there is no extra space needed.

Comment: *Only a span with an odd number of ones can possibly be part of a cross (otherwise there is no middle element).* The definition of *X* here appears not to require the diagonals meet in the middle, just in a common point. This might be worth clarifying in the question or your answer.

Comment: @Patrick87 you are right, rereading the question's exact wording seems to allow also a "V" shape. I will add a remark.

Comment: I agree, this wasn't specified in the test, so I wasn't sure if it should also allow uneven Xs. The problem wasn't really clear about that one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an `O(m*n)` procedure, where `m` is the number of rows and `n` the number of columns in the matrix:

Iterate row by row once from top to bottom. Each `1` can have between zero and two parents. If the `1` has a parent, assign it its parent's parent. Save the cells with two parents. Now do the same for "children", traversing rows from bottom to top. After that, find the cell with two parents and two children that shows the X of greatest size.

```
10001
01010
00100
01010
10001
```

Top to bottom:

```
p1   ...   p2
  p1 ... p2
   [p1,p2] // one cell with two parents
...
...
```

Bottom to top:

```
...
...
   [c1,c2]
  c1 ... c2
c1   ...   c2
```

Answer (score 0):

O(n) space and O(n) time (for n the number of cells):

1. In O(n) time, associate each element of the matrix with the max distance along '1' cells in straight lines NE, SE, SW, and NW (reading the matrix like a map).
2. In O(n) time, find the cell which is both a '1' and has the largest min of these four values. You can do this at the same time as setting the last of the four.
3. The max length is one more than twice the largest min found above.

Comment: To illustrate why step 1 is O(n): Say we want to populate the SE values. Each cell on the S and E side of the matrix has SE_val = 0, then going in from the S & E edge one row/col at a time, each cell gets either SE_val = 0 (if the cell to the SE is 0) or 1 + the SE_val of the cell to the SE. This looks at each cell once per direction. This can be optimized further, but will still be O(n).